# Jquery show div if query returns data

Tags: jquery

I am working with a script that needs to show a DIV which contains a small FORM. I need the FORM to be displayed only when a query to a database returns a result of 1 or more.

I have the MySQL query that looks for data and it is working and populates a var named $alerts, I then echo the content of the var $alerts.

My jQuery script looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        function runrequests() { 
           $.ajax({ 
             url: 'check_request_events.php',
             type:"POST",
             data:"alerts", 
             success: function(data){ //4
             document.getElementById("alerts").innerHTML = data;

               //render the dynamic data into html
             } 
           });  
        };  

               // run it initially
        runrequests();

        // run it every 30 seconds
        setInterval(runrequests, 30 * 1000);
        });
```

The part of the scripts that displays the div is:

```
<div id="alerts">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
<input type="image" src="../../../../conf_images/butler_request.png" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
<input name="RecordID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ClientRecordId;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1" />
<input type="hidden" name="RecordID" value="<?php echo $row_ConfAlert['RecordID']; ?>" />
</form>
```

What do I need to do to only show the DIV when the query returns data greater than 0.

Many thanks in advance for your time and help.

New code
jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        function runrequests() { 
           $.ajax({ 
             url: 'check_request_events.php',
             type:"POST",
             data:"alerts", 
             success: function(data){

                if (data.length > 0){
                    $('#alerts').show();
                } else {
                    $('#alerts').hide();
                }
               //render the dynamic data into html
             } 
           });  
        };  

               // run it initially
        runrequests();

        // run it every 30 seconds
        setInterval(runrequests, 30 * 1000);
        });
```

CSS

```
#alerts {
display:none;
}
```

DIV

```
<div id="alerts">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
<input type="image" src="butler_request.png" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
<input name="RecordID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ClientRecordId;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1" />
<input type="hidden" name="RecordID" value="<?php echo $row_ConfAlert['RecordID']; ?>" />
</form>
</div>
```

Still not hiding the DIV.
Regards

Comment: Can't you use simple `if`? I am sure you must have learned it

Comment: `if (data.length > 0){ //exec code here }` would be the simplest solution however it depends on what format your data is returned in.

Comment: Hi Guys, I have used if (data.length > 0){ document.getElementById("alerts").innerHTML = data;} and it works to a point. The DIV only displays 1 or 0 and not the form within the DIV. Any ideas?

Comment: instead of "document.getElementById("alerts").innerHTML = data;" try it with "$('#alerts').show();" (i assume the id "alerts" has a display:none; in css)

Answer (score 0):

Use the given code. the datattype is json. json encoded data needed  in check_request_events.php.  Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        function runrequests() { 
           $.ajax({ 
             url: 'check_request_events.php',
             type:"POST",
             data:"alerts",
 dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data){ //4
if (data.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("alerts").innerHTML = data;

        }else{
            //alert('no data');
        }

               //render the dynamic data into html
             } 
           });  
        };  

               // run it initially
        runrequests();

        // run it every 30 seconds
        setInterval(runrequests, 30 * 1000);
        });
```

Comment: Hi all, I am still having issues trying to get this to work. I have posted new updated code. Can anyone see where I am going wrong.

Comment: Hi all, resolved. I used: if (data == '1'){ //NOTE '1'
      $('#alerts').show();
     } else {
      $('#alerts').hide();
     }

Answer (score 0):

All that was missing was '' around the data when performing the if statement.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    function runrequests() { 
       $.ajax({ 
         url: 'check_request_events.php',
         type:"POST",
         data:"alert",
         dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){ 

                if (data == '1'){
                    $('#alerts').show();
                } else {
                    $('#alerts').hide();
                }
            } 
        });  
    };  

           // run it initially
    runrequests();

    // run it every 30 seconds
    setInterval(runrequests, 30 * 1000);
});
```